# Sports results datasets

Tags: data-request, sports

Where can I find statistics for sport competitions, like Olympics and international championships?

I'm looking for actual results, like timing in 100m races or rates given to figure skaters.

Sources I found contain limited information (http://www.databaseolympics.com/ has only top three results), or focus on medals (like http://www.theguardian.com/sport/series/london-2012-olympics-data), or didn't work (like Sochi's APIs).

In light of this, detailed sports results would be very appreciated.

Comment: There are already many questions about sport results. Also, many databases focus on a particular sport or competition. Please be more specific, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

the olympics site seems to have all of the data you seek:
http://www.olympic.org/athletics
but it looks like the opposite of open...

the guardian's data store has some of what you seek:
http://www.theguardian.com/sport/series/london-2012-olympics-data
2012 open data
http://www.theguardian.com/sport/datablog/interactive/2012/aug/03/london-2012-results-open-data
more guardian data, in google drive spreadsheet, THIS actually looks close to what you seek:: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AonYZs4MzlZbdHlfd0F1QlAxYjgtOW53ZXNOZ0JzNVE#gid=0
all records for 2012
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AonYZs4MzlZbdFNaMTRsVDNiV1RZaWNGdmJDU1RSSGc#gid=0
some gis data for you:
http://geocommons.com/overlays/16680

wikipedia looks like an optimal choice for data selection; but (i think) you're going to have to work for it:
picked a medal sport: pentathalon; to vague; drill pentathalon down to a random year:
http://web.archive.org/web/20091103091009/http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_pentathlon_at_the_2008_Summer_Olympics
still not the detail wanted...but if you click on the details link in the medalists table, you'll find the information you seek:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_pentathlon_at_the_2008_Summer_Olympics_%E2%80%93_Men%27s
note: i only did this for one medal sport, so i'm not sure if its the same throughout, but knowing wikipedia, i'm sure its the same throughout ;).
offhand, you should get a list off wikipedia off events with links, and use a scraper to ping them all, appending the appropriate details info onto each url ("-Mens, -Womens", etc); i'm willing to bet the table with the detailed info has an id attribute, which i would then nail down to in the scraper, scooping up it and its contents...

you can ping nbc's olympics site via wayback machine for more data, at least going back to athens 2004; wayback had links even older, although i'm not sure if they're the same format
http://www.nbcolympics.com/index.html
http://web.archive.org/web/20040804003859/http://www.nbcolympics.com/index.html
http://web.archive.org/web/20060504132456/http://www.nbcolympics.com/index.html
http://web.archive.org/web/20140103124519/http://www.2008.nbcolympics.com/modernpentathlon/resultsandschedules/index.html
just to show a few
BONUS:
datavis of olympic data howto:
http://datavisualization.ch/inside/how-we-visualized-112-years-of-olympic-games/
olympic datavis example gallery:
http://www.visualizing.org/galleries/peoples-choice-visualizing-london-2012-olympic-games

Comment: Do you suggest screen-scraping? Are you sure it is open data?

Comment: scraping or wget; actually none of this is "open" pe say, although i'm not sure how it cannot be. researching....

Answer (score 0):

For football (soccer), try fantasysportnet http://fantasysportnet.com/data/home.jsp

They cover the major European football leagues … EPL, Bundesliga, Spanish league, Serie A, and provide stats through a simple API.